# Oculus Hand Tracking: Getting the correct velocity of the hand?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

**EDIT:** After doing a little more debugging. It seems that the velocity vector is reading zero (for both methods) for some reason. Any suggestions?

I am trying to make a simple Hand Tracking demo in Unity for the Oculus Quest. I was able to successfully implement a Grab and Release mechanic, similar to this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoSzhoZ18bE&t=2s). It is a little out dated for the state of the Oculus plugin but, the overall logic remains the same.

The only issue I had was implementing a Drop function. When I drop an object I want to add the linear and angular velocity of my hand to the object. I've tried to do this in the following ways:

Grabber script:

```
protected override void GrabEnd()
{
    if (m_grabbedObj)
    {
        Debug.Log("Grabbed object found");
        Rigidbody rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rigid)
        {
            GrabbableRelease(rigid.velocity, rigid.angularVelocity);
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 linearVelocity = (transform.position - lastPointerPos) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            Vector3 angularVelocity = (transform.eulerAngles - lastPointerRot.eulerAngles) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            GrabbableRelease(linearVelocity, angularVelocity);
        }
    }

    GrabVolumeEnable(true);
}
```

Inside of Grabbable:

```
virtual public void GrabEnd(Vector3 linearVelocity, Vector3 angularVelocity)
{
    Rigidbody rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    rb.velocity = linearVelocity;
    rb.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
}
```

There is one more function in-between these two but essentially it just calls GrabEnd on the object passing the velocities with it.

I've also ensured that there are rigidbodies on both the grabber(hands) and the grabbable objects.

`lastPointerPos` & `lastPointerRot` are Vector3's that are saved at the end of FixedUpdate. I am also checking whether I need to call GrabEnd inside of FixedUpdate depending on the PinchStrength and Confidence of the index finger.

The reason I have two methods is just from the two different ways I've tried to solve this issue. Neither one seems to work. The object simply falls straight down on to the floor no matter how I flail my arms like a fool in my living room lol

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try the Oculus-native function `Vector3 velocity = OVRInput.GetLocalControllerVelocity(controller)`. Also see [their docs](https://developer.oculus.com/reference/unity/1.43/class_o_v_r_input/#a284d11ad0469f2b1e04447e2d6a26bd4). You may want to absolutify it via `velocity = rig.TransformDirection(velocity);` Also, there's a similar function for angularVelocity.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken but, in the comments of the function it says that only works with the Touch controllers so I am left to figure out how to calculate it without that function.

Comment: The link works, but it's flaky -- I had to hit reload at times. Gotcha on the Hands vs Controller!

Comment: I was able to calculate a pretty flaky velocity from `transform.parent` however, it does not seem entirely accurate and minuscule in size

Answer (score 0):

In the future the Oculus sdk should support
`OVRInput.GetLocalControllerVelocity((OVRInput.Controller.RTouch))`
to return hand velocity. At the moment they don't have it available.

A simple to implement solution could be something like this:

```
public GameObject RightHandAnchor;
private Vector3 lastPosition;

private void FixedUpdate()
{   
    float speed = Vector3.Distance( lastPosition, RightHandAnchor.transform.position) / Time.deltaTime;
    //update previous positions
    lastPosition = middlePositionVelocity;              
    Debug.log("Speed: " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", speed);

}
```

`